# Towers of Hanoi - Proof of Correctness

Tags: proof-verification, induction, proof-explanation

So I found a lot of proofs, that you need 2^n-1 steps to solve the hanoi tower puzzle. However I am looking for a mathematical proof that shows, that the recurrence in itself is true for all n>1. I want to proof the correctness of the algorithm itself, not that it does 2^n-1 steps for a given n.

The equation to solve the puzzle goes like this:

A = Starttower,
B = Goaltower,
C = Exchangetower

$Hanoi(n,A,B,C)$

1. Move n-1 disks from A to C
2. Move 1 disk from A to B
3. Move n-1 disks from C to B

How can I prove that this recurrence is true and transports als disks from A to B for any number of disks?

I tried induction, but i find it really hard because there is no real equation (like for example with gauss). This is my try:

Base Case: $Hanoi(1,A,B,C)$ is true since it does $Move(A,B)$

IH: I assume $Hanoi(n,A,B,C)$ is correct

Now  I have to show that IH -> $Hanoi(n+1,A,B,C)$

Which is true for all three moves which become n,1 and n.

But my question is, can I just assume that my IH is correct without looking further into the steps of the algorithm?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What do you mean by "Move n-1 = Move n"? How did you arrive at that?

Comment: As long as you're writing things like "n=n+1" you're  going to remain confused about things...

Comment: Just edited my question, i hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

To do this correctly, define the Hanoi process as Hanoi$(n,X,Y,Z)$, where $X$ is your starting tower, $Y$ is your goal, and $Z$ is the third tower.

Now the process Hanoi$(n,A,B,C)$ runs as follows:

- Hanoi$(n-1,A,C,B)$
- Move $1$ disk from $A$ to $B$
- Hanoi$(n-1,C,B,A)$

Note how which towers play which roles switch throughout the process.

Try setting up your induction more carefully now; this should help.

Comment: I just changed my post, do you think this is correct?

Comment: @NilsLcrx Your question is now "Can I just assume that my IH is correct?" That's precisely how all proofs by induction work -- you assume the IH to be correct.

Comment: So the proof is correct like i wrote it down? I just do not feel like i proved anything at this point...

Comment: @NilsLcrx Remember how induction works. You've proved you can do it for $n=1$. Based on that you've proved you can do it for $n=2$. Based on that you've proved you can do it for $n=3$. Etc.